# How does the orientation of a television antenna affect picture quality?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, waves, polarization, applied-physics

I don't understand this and it's supposed to be with regards to polarization

Comment: Given you’re so sure it’s related to polarization, maybe you can explain why you think polarization is more important than orientation?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  "Polarization" is used in a few different senses with regard to TV antennas, and "orientation" with even more different senses.

Comment: What do you mean by *orientation*?  Most antenna are directional and so that one should point an antenna towards the desired transmitter goes almost without saying.  Are you, instead, asking about, e.g., horizontal versus vertical orientation?

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to the answer for this question, as follows.

Broadcast VHF and UHF television signals are horizontally polarized, which require horizontally-disposed dipole elements to receive. This is why the elements of a rooftop TV antenna point sideways and not up-and-down.

Rooftop TV antennas for home reception are also constructed so they pick up signals most strongly from one direction and reject signals that are off-angle. This prevents signals from out-of-area stations on shared channels from interfering with in-area signals. This requires that the receiving antenna be oriented so that the end with the shortest elements on it is pointing straight towards the transmitter location to within about +/- 10 degrees. Outside of this "acceptance cone", the signal-to-noise ratio presented to the receiver is seriously degraded.